# What is this Plastic Strip that came with stair nose?

Tags: flooring, installation, stairs

Bought some stair noses from a warehouse online and it came with this plastic strip.

What is it for? Do I glue this down and then stair nose on top of it?
[image]

Comment: Did it come with instructions? If not, you will need to go to the makers website, and hopefully they have the instructions there. I have installed many types of nosings, all are pretty much the same. This is a new one to me.